# When can raw data can be used to look for phase synchronization between time series?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, signal-processing

I'm studying a system formed by multiple rotors non-linearly coupled to each other. If I want to look for phase synchronization, I could just look at the angle for predefined points around the rotational axis of each rotor and test for phase locking or evaluate the synchronization index. The problem is that the couplings are so strong that those angles don't increase monotonically, in other words, the coupling is also affecting the amplitude of the time series. Can I still read those angles as phases, or do I need to extract another phase from, let's say, the Hilbert transform?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: - Isn't it normal for the coupling to affect the amplitudes? I also wonder: - Aren't the methods you mention more adequate for detecting synchronization between two time series, while your system is closer to a spatially extended one? In general, if you have good validation data (i.e., trustworthy previous measurements you can compare with), you might get away with simpler, more direct methods. In a research context, a more robust method and, better still, using more than one method for crosschecking, is probably a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with stafusa, that nonlinear coupling normally affects amplitudes as well, so don't really bother with it.

I have 3 approaches for you, and I think you should use all 3. The first two, you have already mentioned:

1. Yes, simply check the angles at specific points *in angle space*, similarly to what you suggested. It is always worth it to do the "simple" stuff first before moving to more complex methods. This btw amounts to a stroboscopic projection.
2. Use the Hilbert transform and create a phase for each analytic signal created from the Hilbert transform (the phase is the so-called "argument" of the complex number). The H.T. is a powerful tool for this context and I would be surprised if it was not helpful.
3. Check for dimensionality of data. For two synchronized phases, if you plot them versus each other, the plot should be one-dimensional. If you are reducing the system even further using e.g. a stroboscopic map, then the plot would be 0-dimensional (i.e. discrete series of points that repeat without filling a curve). There is a software package available that can immediately calculate dimensions of datasets: https://juliadynamics.github.io/DynamicalSystems.jl/latest/entropies/#attractor-dimension-estimation . You can use this technique for both the original and the Hilbert-created phases.

Disclaimer: I made the software I cite.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
The main reason why I asked in the first place was that, at least regarding phase locking and synchronization index, I was getting contradictory results from the angles and the phases (methods 1 and 2 respectively).
Anyway, I'm going to check the 3rd method and see what happens. Thank you for the software reference.

Comment: I would tend to pay more attention in the phase of the Hilbert transform in this case. However I have not worked with the system that you are working with and so put a *huge* grain of salt to everything I say.